# Stack more variables in brackets to trigger .remove()

Tags: jquery

Right now I am trying to make an modalbox for self, just to play arround, nothing serious because I am still newbie.

I know that there is possibility to do this:

```
$('#elementOne, #elementTwo, #elementThree').remove();
```

But is there a possibility to add two variables because I can't seem to get it working.
I tried like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('$miniBox_wrap, $miniBox_overlay').remove();
}, 1000);
```

Also like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $($miniBox_wrap, $miniBox_overlay).remove();
}, 1000);
```

Maybe I've done something wrong or it's not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your variables are jQuery objects, use [jQuery's `add` method](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```js
$miniBox_wrap.add( $miniBox_overlay ).remove();
```